# Yii - Joins on tables are not working

Tags: php, join, yii

I want to get the data from two tables. I have used the below code to do so. I am new to Yii, if I am doing it the wrong way, please suggest the right way.

Here is the code of controller:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Users', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>'leave',
        'together'=>true,
        'condition'=>'leave.user_id=:user_id',
        'params'=>array(':user_id'=>$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->getId())->user_id),              
    ),
));

$this->render('admin',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

Here is the code of view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(       
        array(
            'header' => 'Leave Type',
            'name'=>'leave_type',
            'value'=>'$data->leave->leave_type',  
        ),      
        'employee_code',
        'username',
        'password', 
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

**My Problem is:**

I am joining two tables **User** and **Leave**. I want to get the data of users from **Leave** table as well as the users table. the above code shows me data from **user** table, when i try to show data from **Leave** table it throws me following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

**UPDATE**

Here is my user model relations:

```
return array(
    'leaves' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Leaves', 'leave_id'),
    'creator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'created_by'),
    'updator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'modified_by'),   
    'leave' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Leaves', 'user_id'),  
);
```

Here is my leave model relations:

```
return array(
    'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
    'creator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'created_by'),
    'updator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'modified_by'),           
);
```

Comment: What are the relations in Leave Table ?? Can you post it

Comment: Have you declared relation between the Leave model and User model in both models ? also why did you pass model as parameter for :userid. I am talking about the loadmodel thing

Comment: @shanavascet please read the updated question

Comment: Tell me waht does :userid get does it get proper id ?? by using loadmodel() function ??

Comment: You can check check the sql being produced by logging the sql or see the logs in the browser itself.I dont think 'condition'=>'leave.user_id=:user_id', this is required. since you are using join operation and it will happen using the relations without giving extra condition.

Comment: @Ninad yes i have already checked that it get proper id

Comment: You get that error because $data->leave gives you an array of objects as it related to user by HAS_MANY relation

Comment: @Ninad i new to yii so please suggest me what can i use on the place of HAS_MANY ?

Comment: Do you want to display all the leave types of the user or can display single user with that leave type ??

Comment: @Ninad yes i want to get the data of all users..

Answer (score 0):

You can't display `leave` relation, because it's a HAS_MANY, I mean, in your $data->leave you have an array of Leave objects.

You should implement implode function, for example:

```
'value'=> "implode(', ', array_map(function($object) { return $object->leave_type; }, 
           $data->leave))"
```

BTW, `leave` relation i think should be a HAS_ONE instead of HAS_MANY, and in this case, you don't need in an implode function in GridView

Comment: Make var_dump or CVarDumper::dump() of $data->leave and show result somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
'value'=>'$data->leave->leave_type', // WRONG
```

$data->leave = array of objects and you could not access directly leave_type from it. That array was returned from your below relation:

```
'leave' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Leaves', 'user_id'),
```

I'm not sure the leave type which you want to access and relate it with user. But in this case, the solution is you can add more relation to just access first leave record of user

```
'singleLeave' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Leaves', 'user_id'), // add this line on Model User
```

And then you can access it properly
    'value'=>'$data->singleLeave->leave_type',

Actually, in the first approach, the $data->leave should populate array of Leaves and from there, each Leave record should have to go into child views, and this is the point where you have to go detail

Comment: also in CGridView can be done something like this:`'value'=>function ($data,$row) {foreach($data->leave as $leave) echo $leave->leave_type;}` Its if columns must be populated with array.

Comment: I knew, but I'm not sure what he want once map the leave type from many-many relation with one user. If he just need in the one time, just user with one leave (first record from user's children), he wouldn't have to list all of leaves.

Comment: It's not mine '-'. But meh it's rly bad idea))

Comment: Never mind, I just want to point out why OP got wrong. There still has solution to go over it and I emphasized that it would not the best choice. After he applied it and see what wrong happened in his result, he will recognize and reject that choice. If someone feels that is bad idea for reference and down vote my answer, it would be fine because I still have to learn much ahead :)